# Passing a Python Variable To an "IN" of Postgresql

Tags: python, postgresql

Hope you guys doing good today,

I have a python script that pulls a `name` from `stock_picking` table which is :

```
self.env.cr.execute("SELECT name FROM stock_picking WHERE sale_id = %s", [pulled_so_id])
raw_pick = self.env.cr.fetchall()
```

When executed, query above working well and showing result of this three names :

```
[('WH/OUT/00013',), ('WH/OUT/00011',), ('WH/OUT/00012',)]
```

I converted those three result to string, removing several unwanted character, and assigning three of it into a variable. Long story short, it become like this :

```
pulled_picking_name = str(raw_pick5)

#  In my terminal, a variable above now contains clean result of :
#  'WH/OUT/00013','WH/OUT/00011','WH/OUT/00012'
```

And now, i'd like to put this `pulled_picking_name` into an `UPDATE` query in my same python script with this line :

```
 self.env.cr.execute("UPDATE account_move SET partner_id = %s WHERE ref IN (%s)",
                                [pulled_partner_id, pulled_picking_name])
```

But then nothing really happens.

I filled that `IN (%s)` with my self-declared string and it worked well. I also test that three result directly into `psql` with `UPDATE` query above and it worked great also.

But when i'm assigning that three result into variable and pass it to my query, nothing really happens. No error message or anything.

I feel like i'm missing something but i can figured out what it is :(

Please, every help is really appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You absolutely don't need to "convert to string and remove unwanted characters". What you're getting with

```
raw_pick = self.env.cr.fetchall()
# [('WH/OUT/00013',), ('WH/OUT/00011',), ('WH/OUT/00012',)]
```

is a list of row tuples; since each row of your result set has one column, you get 1-tuples.

If you want a plain array of strings (or whatever the first column's datatype is), do

```
raw_pick = [row[0] for row in self.env.cr.fetchall()]
# ['WH/OUT/00013', 'WH/OUT/00011', 'WH/OUT/00012']
```

To use `in`, you'll need to pass in a tuple to the Postgres adapter. Assuming you want to do something to all of those `raw_pick` strings,

```
names = tuple(raw_pick)
self.env.cr.execute(
    "UPDATE account_move SET partner_id = %s WHERE ref IN %s",
    [pulled_partner_id, tuple(raw_pick)],
)
```

does the trick.

Comment: You don't have to convert to a tuple, just keep as list and change `ref IN %s` to `ref  = ANY(%s)` per [List adaptation](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#adapt-list). Added benefit it won't error if the list is empty, whereas an empty tuple and `IN` will.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Good points. I'm used to using tuples with `IN`, per [tuple adaptation](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#tuples-adaptation). :)

Answer (score 1):

More to the point IMHO is why on Earth would are you messing around dragging the data back and fore to some Python code?

```
UPDATE account_move SET partner_id = %s WHERE ref IN (
  SELECT name FROM stock_picking WHERE sale_id = %s
);
```

There are other ways to write that query, but that is just the two parts stuck together.